# how tile screen with my images right same google mapview android

Tags: android, custom-view

I have a image that sliced as png files and in 32*32 size.I only want tile my screen right same google mapview with my images.how can i do it please get me idea and example for doing it.

Comment: can you show any image of your desire view?

Comment: i want implement mapview class myself and I dont have any idea for it

Comment: you can make like yourPackageName.MapView and create a class **MapView** extends with View.

Comment: ok it's very easy but for your information Google map v1 is stopped by google , now available map view is map v2. If I post a usefull link as answer then you accept this? Because it's huge process, this site gives you all the idea. Please give me your feedback. Would you like to integrate Google Map V2 for better clarification.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I know I should use a customview for it but I dont know how implement it I need example code for it

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html  http://www.jayway.com/2012/06/25/creating-custom-android-views-part-1-extending-standard-views-and-adding-new-xml-attributes/ see this...